# How to make an option 'All' in django filters when filtering data

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am developing a django application in which I can filter ingredients based on recipes. I am using django filters to give my user filtration options. My filtration dropdown works perfectly fine but I want to add an option 'All', upon submitting which all ingredients should be listed regardless of their recipe.

Here is my code:

```
#models.py

class Recipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    rules = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.title
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    recipe_id = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    instructions = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    rules = models.TextField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    primal = models.CharField(default='0',max_length=500,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
            return self.title

#forms.py

class RecipeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        fields = ['recipe_id']

#views.py

def ingredient_list(request):
    ingredientfilter = IngredientFilter( queryset=Recipe.objects.filter(user = request.user))
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'recipe_id' in request.GET:
        recipe_id=request.GET['recipe_id'];
        ingredients = Ingredient.objects.filter(recipe_id= recipe_id)
        selected_combo_value = Recipe.objects.get(pk=recipe_id)
        return render(request, 'ingredient_list.html',{'ingredients':ingredients, 'ingredientfilter': ingredientfilter,'selected_combo_value':selected_combo_value })
    else:
        ingredients = Ingredient.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    return render(request, 'ingredient_list.html',{'ingredients':ingredients, 'ingredientfilter': ingredientfilter })
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/261). The workaround is to override the choices for the filter.

```py
class RecipeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RecipeFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters['recipe_id'].field.choices.insert(0, ('', u'---------'))
```